# pre-customer inquiry/ post-customer inquiry

Tags: word-choice, capitalization, dashes

I'm translating titles of paragraphs from Japanese to English. A pragmatic translation of the titles can be: "Before Receiving Inquiries from Potential Customers" and "After Receiving Inquiries from Potential Customers". Underneath each title there is a description of the processes of what to do before and after contact with potential customers.
I would like to make the titles as natural as possible and am considering changing them to:

"Pre-Customer Inquiry" and "Post-Customer Inquiry"

Including the use of the dash, do the above sound natural to native speakers? Or should I stick to the original pragmatic translation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm, the way the titles read now, without the additional information provided by your introduction, indicate to me "*Inquires from people who are not yet customers*" and "*Inquires from people who used to be customers*", respectively. That is, the "Pre-" and "Post-" seem to attach to *customer*, instead of *inquiry*. For that reason, I prefer your pragmatic translations.

Answer (score 1):

Dan Bron's comment is apropos, although this is a common problem when attaching a prefix to a phrase where the key word is not the first word, and often the users will be able to make sense from context. However, a reasonabe compromise would be to use

> Before Customer Inquiry
>
> After Customer Inquiry

Answer (score 0):

You say, "*I would like to make the titles as natural as possible*".  In that case, leave them as you had them originally. You will not do yourself any favors by trying to shorten the expression through just the use of *pre-*/*post-* in place of *before*/*after*.

It is in any case presumably the *receiving* that *pre-* and *post-* would apply to, not the customers or the inquiries. On the other hand, you also speak about *before* and *after* **contact** with the customer.

In sum, keep it simple (and natural): "*Before Receiving Inquiries from Potential Customers*" and "*After Receiving Inquiries from Potential Customers*".  (Or "*Before Customer Contact*" etc.)

If you **must** shorten the expressions (e.g., to save space in a user interface) the try something like *Before Contact*/*After Contact*.